# in Laravel Displaying QR Code in PDF file

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, qr-code, laravel-5.7

I'm facing a problem with displaying a QR code in a PDF file. When I try to display the QR code without PDF it works. The QR code is generated by https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode on to a pdf file generated by https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.8.5

`StudentController.php`:

```
public function view_downlads($id){
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('Student.markscardpdf');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

`Student/markscardpdf.blade.php`:

```
{{ QrCode::size(200)->generate('hello') }}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying QR Code in PDF file, in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887972/displaying-qr-code-in-pdf-file-in-laravel)

Comment: You posted the exact same question twice.