# Displaying QR Code in PDF file, in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

**I'm facing a problem with displaying a QR code in a PDF file. When I try to display the QR code without PDF it works. The QR code is generated by https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode on to a pdf file generated by https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.8.5**

StudentController.php:

```
public function view_downlads($id){
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('Student.markscardpdf');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Student/markscardpdf.blade.php:

```
{{ QrCode::size(200)->generate('hello') }}
```

Comment: how are you embedding it? as an image?

Answer (score 9):

You can use library output within image tag by converting base64 format.

Example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(200)->generate('http://google.com')) !!} ">
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use like this, it will not require the imagick extension.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::size(200)->generate('http://google.com')) !!} ">
```

Comment: Is it possible to send a var inside the generate field?